# Error in jQuery to animate the #hexpand div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance, jquery-ui

I want to expanding it from 121 x 121 pixels to 151 x 151 pixels over the course of three seconds.

I did this but this is not working.

```
#hexpand $( ".animate" ) #hexpand(
{
    width: "151px",
    height: "151px",
},
5000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how animate should be used

```
jQuery('#hexpand').animate({width:151,height:151},400);
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer so it can help others

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#hexpand").animate({
    width: 150,
    height: 150
}, 5000);
```